# Debian 7 + Hyper-V and random network/DNS problems

Tags: networking, debian, hyper-v, debian-wheezy

Our department is *nix-based exclusively but unfortunately the company we're part of runs on a Windows environment and until I get budget for our own servers I have to run our servers on a Hyper-V environment.

I'm having massive issues with networking on my Wheezy VM. Since iniatial install there'd be random problems resolving hostnames when doing a `apt-get update` or `apt-get install <package>` and I'd have to repeat the process a couple of times before it completed successfully.

```
root@gitlab:/home/git/gitlab# apt-get update
Err http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy Release.gpg                                                               
  Something wicked happened resolving 'debian.mirror.ac.za:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg                                                       
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy Release.gpg                           
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release        
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy Release                                      
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Sources                         
Err http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy-updates Release.gpg    
  Something wicked happened resolving 'debian.mirror.ac.za:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy/all Sources            
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy/all amd64 Packages                           
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-en                  
Ign http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy Release                                      
Ign http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy-updates Release        
Ign http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy/all Translation-en     
Ign http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy/main Sources
Hit http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy-updates/main Sources
Get:1 http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages [2905 B]
Ign http://debian.mirror.ac.za wheezy/main Translation-en
Fetched 2905 B in 4s (639 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'debian.mirror.ac.za:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'debian.mirror.ac.za:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Unfortunately, today I was doing sysadmin and updating the Gitlab instance running on this VM and I cannot get the `bundle install` procedure to complete without it failing somewhere random in the list.

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.9) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.8.4) 
Using atomic (1.1.14) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.3) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.38) 
Using activesupport (4.0.2) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.2) 
Using mime-types (1.25.1) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.2) 
Using actionpack-action_caching (1.1.0) 
Using actionpack-page_caching (1.0.2) 
Using activemodel (4.0.2) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.1) 
Using activerecord (4.0.2) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.2) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.10.1) 
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1) 
Using rails (4.0.2) 
Using acts-as-taggable-on (2.4.1) 
Using asciidoctor (0.1.4) 
Using descendants_tracker (0.0.3) 
Using ice_nine (0.10.0) 
Using axiom-types (0.0.5) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2) 
Using sass (3.2.12) 
Using bootstrap-sass (3.0.3.0) 
Using json (1.8.1) 
Using carrierwave (0.9.0) 
Using timers (1.1.0) 
Using celluloid (0.15.2) 
Using charlock_holmes (0.6.9.4) 
Using coercible (1.0.0) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (2.0.2) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using coffee-rails (4.0.1) 
Using colored (1.2) 
Using connection_pool (1.2.0) 
Using d3_rails (3.1.10) 
Using orm_adapter (0.5.0) 
Using warden (1.2.3) 
Using devise (3.0.4) 
Using devise-async (0.8.0) 
Using diff-lcs (1.2.5) 
Using dotenv (0.9.0) 
Using email_validator (1.4.0) 

Bundler::HTTPError: Network error while fetching https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/enumerize-0.7.0.gemspec.rz
An error occurred while installing enumerize (0.7.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install enumerize -v '0.7.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

One thing to point out is that the problem was limited to just `apt-get` before this and I've managed to upgrade the Gitlab instance a few times.

I've tried with both the Legacy Network Adapter and the normal one and have checked the the Hyper-V IC modules have been loaded:

```
root@gitlab:/home/git/gitlab# lsmod | grep hv
hv_utils               12986  0 
hv_storvsc             17423  2 
hv_netvsc              18304  0 
hv_vmbus               32029  4 hv_netvsc,hv_storvsc,hid_hyperv,hv_utils
scsi_mod              162269  5 libata,sr_mod,sg,hv_storvsc,sd_mod
```

I've also set `/etc/resolve.conf` to our internal DNS servers and 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 with no difference.

What else could be causing this? I'm really started to run out of ideas now.